# problem with text length iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4

Hi dear friends
i have 495 cells and a textField  for inserting number and selecting the  row according to the  cell number .

i have problem with this code :

```
int MAX_LENGTH = 495;
(MAX_LENGTH >[myTextField.text length]{
          myTextField.text = @"ERORR";
```

and this :

```
 for(int i = 0; i <[myTextField.text intValue]; i++) {
[myScrollTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

when user insert a number greater than 495 my app crashes so , how can i  mix them to work fine ! ?

i try to use if / else if / if if but neither worked !
thanks a lot ,

Comment: Add more context, where is the code? How the two sections relate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your check is wrong. It is not the max length, if user enter "1000", the length is 4, and it will absolutely less than your MAX_LENGTH

Replace this:

```
int MAX_LENGTH = 495;
(MAX_LENGTH >[myTextField.text length]{
          myTextField.text = @"ERORR";
```

with

```
int MAX_NUMBER = 495;
NSString *inputtedText = myTextField.text;
NSInteger inputtedNumber = [inputtedText intValue];
if (inputtedNumber > MAX_NUMBER) {
  myTextField.text = @"ERROR";
}
```